# memory separation in v8 for different contexts

Tags: chromium, v8

I am a freshman to learn chromium and v8. I know that the main thread in the renderer process is bound to an Isolate in v8, and an Isolate can possess several Contexts. But I am confused about the memory layout in an Isolate with multiple Contexts.

v8 said that context is used to provide isolated execution environment for JS scripts in a different frame or world. So what is the memory boundary among these contexts? Does each context has a separated stack and heap? And if multiple stacks or heaps exist, how v8 maintains and switches them?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Isolates* provide isolated execution environments. Between different contexts, some limited amount of interaction is possible.

Every isolate has one heap (and stack). When there are multiple contexts in an isolate, they all share the same heap.

The "memory boundary" between contexts consists of access checks that V8 performs in certain places.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I can scan the current memory, is it possible to know which context where the JS code runs? And can you share some links about the access checks in v8? Link for the checks in source code is also helpful. Thanks again for your explanation.

Comment: Every `JSFunction` has a `context()`, which points to the end of a context chain whose other end is the "native context" which represents the API's `Context`. -- Access checks are a complex system, start by grepping for `is_access_check_needed`.